# Acceleration question

Tags: calculus

A particle moves along the $x$-axis so that its velocity is given by $v(t)=5+3.1\cos(0.8t)$ for $t\geq 0$. What is the acceleration of the particle at $t=4$.

I differentiated this and got:

$a(t)=-2.48 \sin(0.8t) $

and plugged in $4$ and got

$a(4) = -0.138437$

But none of the answer choices fit the answer, am I wrong or is the question wrong?

Answer choices: $-0.045$, $-0.145$, $-0.181$, $0.145$, $5.145$

Comment: $t$ is expressed in radians!!

Comment: Yes, check your calculations, making sure that your calculator is in radian mode.

Comment: It is... I dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: Check again. I have obtained you result in DEG mode.

Comment: Ok my calculator is weird, i entered it on wolfram and got around 0.145 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instructions:

1. Click the start button.
2. Open calculator.
3. Click "view" and select Scientific.
4. Click on the radio button "Radians"
5. Redo your computation.
6. Get $0.1447678757...$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2.48sin%280.8*4%29+in+radians 
why does it say its +0.145 here... which one to go with?D:

Comment: @Panthy It is 0.145. That was a typo. SORRY!

Answer (score 1):

v(t)=5+3.1cos (0.8t)

Differentiating with respect to t

We get

a(t)=3.1*(-sin (0.8t))*0.8
=-2.48sin (0.8t)

a(4)=-2.48sin (3.2)
=-2.48sin (3.14-3.2)
=+2.48sin(0.06)
=+2.48*0.06=+0.1488

Note that the answer here is a round about value as pi is approximately equal to 3.14 and sinx is approximately equal to x for x<0.5

This is the answer if you don't want to use a calculator. :)